# Grouping by key and aggregating with custom criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'a', 'web'],
                   ['A', 'b', 'mobile'],
                   ['B', 'c', 'web'],
                   ['C', 'd', 'web'],
                   ['D', 'e', 'mobile'],
                   ['D', 'f', 'web'],
                   ['D', 'g', 'web'],
                   ['D', 'g', 'web']],

columns=['seller_id', 'item_id', 'selling_channel'])
```

It shows selled items with information about who was the seller and what selling channel (in example above it can be web or mobile, but there are more potential channels in real data) was used to sell item

I would like to determine which of the selling channels is the main one for given sell id - but there are additional constraints into that:

1. if one of the channels was used for 75% or more of the sells - this channel will be the main one
2. if none of the channels has at least 75% - name of the main channel should be `mixed`

so for input above I am expecting following output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'mixed'],
                   ['B', 'web'],
                   ['C', 'web'],
                   ['D', 'web']],

columns=['seller_id', 'main_selling_channel'])
```

Right now I am doing that by manually iterating over every dataframe's row to build map where per seller_id I am listing each channel and how much occurrences it was. Then I am iterating over that data again to determine which channel is main. But this manual iteration takes lots of time already when I have 10k lines of input - and the actual data contains couple millions of entries.

I was wondering if there is any effective way of doing that with pandas api instead of manual iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `df.groupby` with value counts with `normalize=True` to check pct of values in each group  , then  check if % is greater than or equal to 0.75  , then using `np.where` set the values which return Tue to `mixed` , finally `df.groupby()` with `idxmax` will return 1 value else `mixed`

```
a = (df.groupby('seller_id')['selling_channel'].value_counts(normalize=True).ge(0.75)
       .rename('Pct').reset_index())

out = (a.assign(selling_channel=np.where(a['Pct'],a['selling_channel'],'mixed'))
       .loc[lambda x: x.groupby('seller_id')['Pct'].idxmax()].drop('Pct',1))
```

---

```
print(out)

  seller_id selling_channel
0         A           mixed
2         B             web
3         C             web
4         D             web
```

Comment: `seller_id` D should be web, not mobile.

Comment: @TYZ thanks, wasnt as simple as I thought. edited my answer , guess it's not worth a downvote anymore :)

Comment: It worked - thanks! and it (on the sample of 100k inputs) was around 15x faster, then manual iterations - for 2.6kk it took 3.1 secs to calculate

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant way, but does the job:

```
temp = df.groupby(["seller_id", "selling_channel"])\
         .count().reset_index()\
         .groupby("seller_id")["item_id"].agg(["max", "sum"])
temp

    max sum
seller_id       
A   1   2
B   1   1
C   1   1
D   3   4

top_channel = df.groupby("seller_id")["selling_channel"]\
                .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
top_channel

seller_id
A    mobile
B       web
C       web
D       web

temp["selling_channel"] = top_channel
final = temp.apply(lambda r: "mixed" if r["max"]/r["sum"]<0.75 else r["selling_channel"], axis=1).to_frame().reset_index()
final.columns = ["seller_id", "main_selling_channel"]

    seller_id   main_selling_channel
0   A   mixed
1   B   web
2   C   web
3   D   web
```